# CakePHP sha1 gives wrong hash

Tags: php, cakephp, hash, sha1, password-encryption

I have a problem with *SimplePasswordHasher* in CakePHP.

For example when I hashed "`h`" I get:

```
761e523c2f835beeb39c69b0d1b717893c5a5c62
```

but I know from several different sources that right solution is actually

```
27d5482eebd075de44389774fce28c69f45c8a75
```

My code in CakePHP:

```
$passwordHasher = new SimplePasswordHasher(array('hashType' => 'sha1'));
    $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash(
        $this->data[$this->alias]['password']
);
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You don't do anything wrong, but the `hash` method uses the salt defined in `app/Config/core.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not tell `WRONG` better call it `DIFFERENT`. And you will get different hash if you change the `salt` value on `app/Config.core.php` on your same CakephpApp. Learn about [Salt](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.fasthash).

Comment: Thanks! I disable "salting" with $hash = Security::hash('h'); But what if I want enable salting again and using same salt in my android client? Do you know how CakePHP exactly using  the salt in hash process?